# SQL - How to list all tuples in a relation such that tuple 1 is greater than tuple 2

Tags: sql, database

Suppose that I have a relation with only 1 column "Value (INT)" and its values are in descending order.

```
+----------+
+  VALUE   +
+----------+
+    10    +
+    9     +
+    8     +
+    7     +
....
```

How can list all the combinations which contains two tuples such that the first tuple is greater than the second tuple

Note: It may exist two tuples with same value

The desired outputs should be like: (10,9) (10, 8)  (9,8), (9,7) (8,7)

Comment: Could you give an example of your desired output? I'm not quite sure what you mean by comparing two tuples.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks. I've added them to my question

Comment: "*and its values are in descending order"* - no they are not. Rows in a table are **not** "ordered".

Answer (score 3):

You can do a cross join on the same table.

```
SELECT t1.VALUE AS VALUE1, t2.VALUE AS VALUE2
FROM thing t1 JOIN thing t2 ON (t1.VALUE != t2.VALUE AND t1.VALUE > t2.VALUE)
```

Comment: The `t1.VALUE != t2.VALUE` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that a single tuple may apear only twice on the left side of the resultset, am I right? That's why there is no (10,7)? 
Then you need to compute row number.

```
select t1.value, t2.value
from
(
    select t.value, row_number(order by t.value) as rnum
    from table t
) t1 inner join
(
    select t.value, row_number(order by t.value) as rnum
    from table t
) t2 on t1.value > t2.value and t1.rnum < t2.rnum + 2
```

Performance of this query will be pretty bad, but I don't know what database are you using - I've used MS SQL row_number function.

**Another idea**:
If you are using SQL Server 2012+ and your answer to the question posed at the begining of this post is positive, you can use:

```
select t.value, lead(t.value,1,0) over(order by t.value desc) as lead1
    lead(t.value,2,0) over(order by t.value desc) as lead2
from table t
```

You may need to handle 0 (defulat value if there is no "lead" tuple). I'm not sure if output in this form is acceptable.

And here you go with **cursor** solution:

```
DECLARE @result TABLE
(
    value1 int,
    value2 int
);
DECLARE
    @value int,
    @lag1 int,
    @lag2 int

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT value
FROM table
ORDER BY value desc
OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @lag2;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @lag1;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @value;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT @result(value1, value2) SELECT @lag2, @lag1
    INSERT @result(value1, value2) SELECT @lag2, @value

    SET @lag2 = @lag1
    SET @lag1 = @value

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @value

END
CLOSE c;
```

Again, I used MS SQL syntax. If you write how you want duplicates handled, I can update the solution.

Comment: "*If you are using SQL Server 2012+*" - or Postgres, or Oracle, or DB2, or Teradata ....

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right. I wanted to point out that there is no LEAD function in older MS SQL versions.